# why does open vpn show this

Tags: openvpn

What does this mean when running **service openvpn start** :

```
openvpn.service - OpenVPN service 
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled
Active: active (exited) since Wed 2017-08-02 11:25:41 SAST 47min ago
Process: 20484 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 20484 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
CPU: 3ms

Aug 02 11:25:41 server systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN service...
Aug 02 11:25:41 server systemd[1]: Started OpenVPN service.
```

does this mean something is wrong because I've seen other outputs from other people saying this like

```
VPN 'server' is running
```

What did I do wrong or what is wrong, that caused mine to have that long output instead of having the shorter output.

tun0 is also not showing up 
I am running ubuntu server 17.04

Thank you

Comment: This looks like the standard output for a systemd service for me. Maybe the short output has been there before systemd, which is the default since 15.04, I think.

Comment: @ByteCommander okay thats good, but is it also normal for **tun0** not to show up when typing **ifconfig** after starting the server ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. I'm not using OpenVPN.

Comment: okay but thanks a lot for the first answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Good news, bad news.

Your `systemd` output is normal.  I have a fully functional OpenVPN server running and it too shows **active (exited)** as its status.

The bad news is, though, that if you configured your OpenVPN server to have a `tun0` interface, it should indeed show up in the `ifconfig` output.
Mine looks like this:

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::24bb:8c51:1da2:1154/64 Scope:Link
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:244 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:357 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:16616 (16.6 KB)  TX bytes:39970 (39.9 KB)
```